# Wrong this in inherited static class method

Tags: typescript

The question refers to TypeScript typing issue.

This piece of code

```
class Foo {
  static classFoo() {
    return new this();
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  instanceBar() {}
}


Bar.classFoo().instanceBar();
```

results in error:

> Property 'instanceBar' does not exist on type 'Foo'

Of course, this isn't true because `this === Bar` when `Bar.classFoo()` is called.  With type errors being ignored, code works as expected, due to how inheritance works in ES6 classes.

Why does this happen? Is it a known bug? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11793), current workaround is

```
class Foo {
  static classFoo<T extends Foo>(this: { new (): T } & typeof Foo): T {
    return new this();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Sadly, it looks like generics are the only way to make it work indeed. `this: { new (): T }` looks neat but may cause troubles, probably moving it to IFoo would be better.

Comment: Indeed it's too strict, you can't use any other static `Foo` methods in `classFoo()`. But typing it as `this: { new (): T} & typeof Foo` should fix that, I updated the answer. And I don't think it's too broad - basically it says  "for any `T` that extends `Foo`, `classFoo()` returns `T` ".

Comment: Yes, it looks solid. Thanks, that's a good use of `this` param after all.